# RecyclerView swipe to delete in Fragment

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I made an swipe to delete functionality in my recycleView and i want to add another background when item is swiped across the screen.

I'm using tutorial for this: https://medium.com/@zackcosborn/step-by-step-recyclerview-swipe-to-delete-and-undo-7bbae1fce27e

I wrote some code, but i have an **java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment PatientsFragment{dcddb65} not attached to a context.**

```
public class PatientsFragment extends Fragment {

    ClinicViewModel clinicViewModel;
    private final ColorDrawable background= new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.patients_fragment, container, false);


        FloatingActionButton fab = root.findViewById(R.id.fabAddPatient);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                AddPatientFragment addPatientFragment = new AddPatientFragment();
                FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
                fm.beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment, addPatientFragment)
                        .addToBackStack(null)
                        .commit();
            }
        });

        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) root.findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewPatients);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        final PatientsAdapter adapter = new PatientsAdapter();
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        clinicViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(ClinicViewModel.class);
        clinicViewModel.getAllPatients().observe(this, new Observer<List<Patient>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(List<Patient> patients) {
                adapter.setPatients(patients);
            }
        });

        new ItemTouchHelper(new ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0,
                ItemTouchHelper.LEFT | ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT) {



            @Override
            public boolean onMove(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildDraw(@NonNull Canvas c, @NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, float dX, float dY, int actionState, boolean isCurrentlyActive) {
                super.onChildDraw(c, recyclerView, viewHolder, dX, dY, actionState, isCurrentlyActive);
                View itemView = viewHolder.itemView;
                int backgroundCornerOffset = 20;

                if (dX > 0) { // Swiping to the right
                    background.setBounds(itemView.getLeft(), itemView.getTop(),
                            itemView.getLeft() + ((int) dX) + backgroundCornerOffset,
                            itemView.getBottom());

                } else if (dX < 0) { // Swiping to the left
                    background.setBounds(itemView.getRight() + ((int) dX) - backgroundCornerOffset,
                            itemView.getTop(), itemView.getRight(), itemView.getBottom());
                } else { // view is unSwiped
                    background.setBounds(0, 0, 0, 0);
                }
                background.draw(c);

            }

            @Override
            public void onSwiped(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {
                clinicViewModel.deletePatient(adapter.getPatientAt(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()));
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Patient deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            }
        }).attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);

        return root;
    }


}
```

Any ideas why?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can't call `getResources()` in a field initializer. Move the `ColorDrawable` instantiation to `onAttach()`, or to a later lifecycle method. Also, please provide the complete stack trace when asking about an Exception, not just the first line.

Comment: I moved ColorDrawable instantiation to onAttach() and it works. Thanks!